# Why isn't my user alert code in Swift working as intended

Tags: swift

I have a reset button in my app. I've coded it so that if users tap on this to reset the app they are presented with a user alert first. This alert provides info and offers two choices: (1) Cancel, (2) Continue.

The idea is that if they tap on Cancel the game won't reset. But if they tap on Continue, the game will reset.

**ISSUE 1**

At present, when the user taps on the reset button, the game is reset immediately **before** the alert displays. After the alert does display, if they tap 'Cancel' nothing more happens, but if they tap 'Continue' the game is reset again!

So, on the face of it the alert buttons work as they should - it's just that tapping the Reset icon already actions the reset before the alert appears.

**ISSUE 2**

My alert code caters for iOS 8 and above users as well as pre-iOS 8 users. How do I alter this part of the code to also offer pre-iOS 8 users the ability to either 'Cancel' or 'Continue'? At present they just get a 'Continue' option.

My code for the alerts is below:

```
@IBAction func buttonResetGame(sender: UIButton) {

    if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Info", message: "This will reset your score and questions.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        // add the Continue button and action
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Continue", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Destructive, handler: {action in

            // do this...
            self.ResetGame()
        }))

        // add the Cancel button and action
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil))

        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }else{
        // For pre-iOS 8 users
        let alert = UIAlertView()
        alert.title = "Info"
        alert.message = "This will reset your score and questions."
        alert.addButtonWithTitle("Continue")
        alert.show()
    }
    ResetGame()

}
```

If it's relevant, my code for resetting the game is below:

```
func ResetGame() {
    PlaySoundReset()
    score = 0
    totalquestionsasked = 0
    SaveScore()
    LoadScore()
}
```

Comment: There is a `ResetGame()` after the `else`-block which simply always gets executed - what do you expect?

Comment: D'oh! I knew I shouldn't have been working on this so late, that is so obvious that it's embarrassing! Curious though, why was it happening immediately (.i.e before the alert came up)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the extra ResetGame() call after your if/else:

```
@IBAction func buttonResetGame(sender: UIButton) {

    if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Info", message: "This will reset your score and questions.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        // add the Continue button and action
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Continue", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Destructive, handler: {action in

            // do this...
            self.ResetGame()
        }))

        // add the Cancel button and action
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil))

        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }else{
        // For pre-iOS 8 users
        let alert = UIAlertView()
        alert.title = "Info"
        alert.message = "This will reset your score and questions."
        alert.addButtonWithTitle("Continue")
        alert.show()
    }
    ResetGame() //remove this line ? You are calling the RestGame func...

}
```

For the second part of your question, you need to set the delegate of the alert view to 'self' or whatever, then implement UIAlertViewDelegate method:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(2_0, 9_0);
```

Where the button index will give you each button i.e. 0 and 1.